# Dot (.) Meta character Php Regex

Tags: php, regex

Dot (.) Meta character is not matching text and showing zero(o) output. Please tell me what i am missing in this code.

```
$string = 'pakistan';
echo preg_match('/p.n/',$string);
```

Comment: Use `+`(_one or more_) or `*`(_zero or more_) quantifier after `.`. Use `/p.*n/` or `/p.+n/`.

Comment: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html on this page there is an example which showing the same example without any + or * sing and i try this example and it is producing 1 output why? i Just change my string and now it is not showing  0 output.

Comment: `.` is used to match any single character except newline. As there are many characters between `p` and `n`, you'll need to use quantifiers. Your current regex will match `pan`, `p*n`, `pun`, `pin`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
preg_match("/p.*n/U", $string, $match);   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($match[0]);
```

If you want to count how many times specific word is repeating in the string

Use [preg_match_all](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match_all.htm)

```
preg_match_all ("/p.*n/U", $string, $match);   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($match[0]);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: if i use Preg_match and print it also give me same output. then why i have to use preg_match_all?

Comment: If you want to count how many times word is repeating in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex:

```
$string = 'pakistan';
echo preg_match('~^p.+n$~',$string);
```

Anchors the string to the beginning and end and requires at least *one* (but unlimited times) character between `p` and `n`.